# Effect of ionization on dipole moment

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, dipole

Suppose we have a non-dipolar molecule such as carbon dioxide. If carbon dioxide is ionized by some means in the gas-phase, will it develop a dipole moment? I am asking with reference to microwave spectroscopy, because the selection rule requires the presence of a permanent dipole moment. In the interstellar space,  $HCO_2^+$ has been detected and it does have a microwave spectrum, because it does have a dipole moment. However, carbon dioxide's dipole moment is zero, so its ordinary microwave spectrum does not exist. There are very weak lines due to its quadrupole.

Comment: So, you ask if CO2 cation could be detected?

Comment: Indirectly yes, but the main idea is can we make non-polar molecular as dipolar (having a non-zero dipole moment) by ionizing them?

Comment: You should propose an electronic structure for the radical cation in question.

Comment: Yes there can be a dipole due to the fact that a *molecular* ion is not a point charge but an unbalanced distributions of charges.

Comment: @Alchimista I don't think that is true. Whether a species possesses a dipole moment is ultimately down to its symmetry. Is there a good reason why a molecular ion can't belong to (for instance) a $D_{5h}$ point group? Cyclopentadienyl immediately springs to mind. Such a species will not have a permanent dipole moment  - a charge and quite possibly a quadrupole, but not a dipole. My guess is the loss of electrons distorts the structure into a point group which can display a dipole moment, but that is purely a guess.

Comment: @Ian Bush Sure, it can be that a ion has enough symmetry to have zero dipole moment. I did not say that one must have it. In fact, you said the same as in my comment.

Comment: @Karl, I do not know enough quantum mechanics to propose the electronic structure of ionized carbon dioxide. What a microwave spectroscopist told me is that sometimes ionization may decrease or sometime it may increase the dipole moment. He was not sure either. May be physicists know this better.

Comment: Well, ionization can change geometry - I wouldn't be surprised if CO2+ was bent instead of linear.

Comment: I think geometry change would be likely. This seems more like a complex problem, because bent carbon dioxide will not rotate in the same way as linear carbon dioxide (different moment of inertia). Interesting perspective!

Comment: Actually it seems to me that this particular case is simple as for symmetry likely has a dramatic change. But what I wanted to say above is that a dipole moment can result because a distribution of n negative charges and n-1 (or n+1) positive charges is not a single charge. Forget molecule for a while and see it from a basic pov. The distribution orients itself in an electrical field.

Comment: In addition to a possible geometry change, ionization of a closed-shell molecule results in an unpaired electron and a (large) magnetic dipole moment. This can facilitate the observation of magnetic-dipole transitions in the rf and microwave range of the spectrum.